# Как вставить html блок после последнего элемента из псевдо массива?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Есть блок элементов с картинками, к примеру, по 5 штук, то есть галерея. И есть кнопка load more. При нажатии на кнопку, после последнего элемента вставляется еще один такой же. И так сколько угодно раз. Но у меня блок вставляется всегда после первого блока, а не последнего.

```js
const galleryWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__wrapper'),
  loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.gallery__load-link');

let galleryWrapper;
for (let i = 0; i <= galleryWrappers.length; i++) {
  if (i == galleryWrappers.length - 1) {
    galleryWrapper = galleryWrappers[i];
  }
}

function createGalleryPart(amount) {
  let newWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  newWrapper.classList.add('gallery__wrapper');

  let wrapperAmount = document.createElement('p');

  let newItem = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement('img');
    item.classList.add('gallery__item');
    item.src = `./img/gallery0${i+1}.jpg`;
    item.alt = `image ${i+1}`;
    newItem.push(item);
  }
  wrapperAmount.textContent = gAmount;
  newItem.push(wrapperAmount);
  newWrapper.append(...newItem);
  galleryWrapper.after(newWrapper);
}

loadMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createGalleryPart(6)
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас была проблема в том, что запускали поиск последнего элемента галереи единожды, а его нужно было запускать каждый раз при нажатии кнопки "показать еще".

Я немного подправил ваш код. Сильно не трогал, чтоб вы поняли, где именно не хватало правки.

Цикл поиска последнего элемента я убрал полностью.

```js
let galleryWrapper;
for (let i = 0; i <= galleryWrappers.length; i++) {
  if (i == galleryWrappers.length - 1) {
    galleryWrapper = galleryWrappers[i];
  }
}
```

Вместо него, последний элемент теперь ищет эта строка

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__wrapper:last-child')[0]
```

```js
const loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector('.gallery__load-link');

function createGalleryPart(amount) {
  let newWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  newWrapper.classList.add('gallery__wrapper');

  let wrapperAmount = document.createElement('p');

  let newItem = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement('img');
    item.classList.add('gallery__item');
    item.src = `./img/gallery0${i+1}.jpg`;
    item.alt = `image ${i+1}`;
    newItem.push(item);
  }
  //wrapperAmount.textContent = gAmount;
  wrapperAmount.textContent = `test ${document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__wrapper').length+1}`;
  newItem.push(wrapperAmount);
  newWrapper.append(...newItem);
  document.querySelectorAll('.gallery__wrapper:last-child')[0].after(newWrapper);
}

loadMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createGalleryPart(6)
});
```

```css
.gallery__wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="gallery__wrapper">photo 1</div>
  <div class="gallery__wrapper">photo 2</div>
  <div class="gallery__wrapper">photo 3</div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="gallery__load-link">more</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваше решение помогло, только такой метод поиска последнего элемента у меня не сработал, выдает ошибку. я воспользовался следующим способом: galleryWrapper[galleryWrapper.length-1].after(newWrapper);